# Python: Need a module for catching typo errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have imported a database table into pandas dataframe. One of the columns is a string where i want to implement a check for typo errors, double typed words.

Is there a module that can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double typed words can be easily found "manually" (I mean by looking for consecutive duplicates). For typo errors, there used to be a library, namely pyenchant, that relies on enchant to do some spellchecking. However, **it is no longer maintained**, but you can still use it.

Some references:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/ and 
https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant

Comment: Thanks..this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

sharing a useful resource that i just discovered for others reference. Below is an index of python modules for spell checking..

https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=spellcheck